# List View vbnet

Tags: mysql, sql, .net, vb.net, winforms

I'm having trouble viewing the saved items in ListView.

The `1` is the `Item No` and the `c001` is the `Item Code` but:

[image]

What's wrong with my code?

```
ListView1.Items.Clear()

sql = "SELECT * FROM inventory"
Try
    dbcomm = New MySqlCommand(sql, dbconn)
    dbread = dbcomm.ExecuteReader()

    While dbread.Read
        ListView1.Items.Add(dbread("itemNo"))
        ListView1.Items.Add(dbread("itemCode"))
    End While

    dbread.Close()
Catch ex As Exception
    MsgBox("Error in collecting data from Database. Error is :" & ex.Message)
    dbread.Close()
    Exit Sub
End Try
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should add your second item in your `SubItems` rather than `Items`. Change this:

```
While dbread.Read
    ListView1.Items.Add(dbread("itemNo")) 'placed in row #1
    ListView1.Items.Add(dbread("itemCode")) 'placed in row #2
End While
```

Into:

```
While dbread.Read
    ListView1.Items.Add(dbread("itemNo")).SubItems.Add(dbread("itemCode")) 'both placed in row #1
End While
```

This way, you place them side-by-side. Not one row after another.

Answer (score 2):

Each time you call `Items.Add` it adds a completely new item (it also returns a reference to the item you added)

What you need to do is to set the `SubItem` text of each item you add. You can use the returned item reference to do this like so (requires `Option Infer On`):

```
    While dbread.Read
        Dim lvi = ListView1.Items.Add(dbread("itemNo"))
        lvi.SubItems.Add(dbread("itemCode"))
    End While
```